# 'To do' list before unpublish app from store

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, app-store

Is there any guideline before unpublish app from App Store and Google Play? Like do I need to backup the Certificates, Identifier & Profile from Apple developer first?

I just worry if in future I would like to republish the app, I might missed out something to release back the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of iOS Apps :

> - You just need to take care of latest source & bundle you are using no other things required to backup
> - Also you can take back up of graphics assets, Any keys you are using on live push notification certificates, Facebook App ID, Ad Ids
>     something like you can take a record of all in 1 version control sheet
> - Regarding app certificates & provisioning can be revoked any time so that will not be an issue

In case of Android Apps :

> - Specifically you have to take back of the key store files along with the password. This is something that if you will loose them you
>     will not be able to submit that app in future with same bundle id. So
>     its important
> - Other is similar as iOS Apps you need to take back of latest source, assets & keys & also create a version control documentation

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very appreciated your guideline.